# UIBarButtonItem not appearing after I successfully add it to navigationitem

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

This task seems pretty straightforward.  You can see from the logs below that I check whether it's being set successfully and it is.  So any idea why it's not showing up when the nav controller pushes to this view?  Does it have something to do with the difference between navigationItem and [navigationBar items]?

```
    NSLog(@"Nav bar's item is: %@", [[[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] items] objectAtIndex:0] description]);
    NSLog(@"The navigationItem's Right bar button is: %@", [[[self navigationItem] rightBarButtonItem] description]);

    //create bar button item with segmented control as custom view
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil]];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
    NSLog(@"Created bar button item: %@", barButtonItem);
    NSLog(@"Bar button item's view is: %@", [barButtonItem customView]);

    //add segmented control bar button item to navigation bar

    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
    NSLog(@"Added bar button item, %@, to nav item %@", barButtonItem, [self navigationItem]);
    NSLog(@"Now Nav bar's item is: %@", [[[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] items] objectAtIndex:0] description]);
    NSLog(@"Now the navigationItem's Right bar button is: %@", [[[self navigationItem] rightBarButtonItem] description]);
```

Logs

```
     Nav bar's item is: <UINavigationItem: 0x7586a60>
     The navigationItem's Right bar button is: (null)
     Created bar button item: <UIBarButtonItem: 0x90a2180>
     Bar button item's view is: <UISegmentedControl: 0x90a11e0; frame = (0 0; 101 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x90a1150>>
     Added bar button item, <UIBarButtonItem: 0x90a2180>, to nav item <UINavigationItem: 0x909c5a0>
     Now Nav bar's item is: <UINavigationItem: 0x7586a60>
     Now the navigationItem's Right bar button is: <UIBarButtonItem: 0x90a2180>
```

But nothing shows up in the nav bar except the default back button.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the NavigationItem to NavigationBar?
Looks like you haven't done it in your code snippet.

As in your log says before you created the Navigationitem:

```
Nav bar's item is: <UINavigationItem: 0x7586a60>
```

And after, still the same:

```
Now Nav bar's item is: <UINavigationItem: 0x7586a60>
```